# why the map does not grow when i resize its container?

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers

I have a map in a small div, but when i click a button i added an event to resize its container but the map only shows the first size.

```js
$(".extender").on("click", () => {
  if ($(".tabs").hasClass("col-lg-6")) {
    $(".introduce").attr("hidden", "");
    $(".tabs").removeClass("col-lg-6").addClass("col-lg-12");
    $(".extender").text("Encoger");
  } else if ($(".tabs").hasClass("col-lg-12")) {
    $(".introduce").removeAttr("hidden");
    $(".tabs").removeClass("col-lg-12").addClass("col-lg-6");
    $(".extender").text("Extender");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs col-lg-6 ">
  <div class="main-card card">
    <div class="card-header ms-auto">
      <ul class="preview-tab nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="map-item-tab" role="tab" aria-controls="map-item" aria-selected="true" href="#map-item" data-bs-toggle="tab">Mapa</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="encuesta-tab-tab" role="tab" aria-controls="encuesta-tab" aria-selected="false" href="#encuesta-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab">Encuesta</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="chat-tab-tab" role="tab" aria-controls="chat-tab" aria-selected="false" href="#chat-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab">Chat</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="social-tab-tab" role="tab" aria-controls="social-tab" aria-selected="false" href="#social-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab">Social</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="descarga-tab-tab" role="tab" aria-controls="descarga-tab" aria-selected="false" href="#descarga-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab">Descargar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="nav-tabContent" class="tab-content">
        <div id="map-item" class="tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="map-item-tab">
          <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-md-center" id="map">
            <button class="extender">Extender</button>

          </div>
        </div>
```

[image: on load]
[image: map extended]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve] for faster troubleshooting. As is, the question contains incomplete code and cannot be answered quickly

Comment: You may need to call `map.updateSize()` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#updateSize

Comment: @Mike Thank you